# How does the implicitly generated move constructor work in c++?

Tags: c++

So the move constructor:

```
foo(foo &&)
```

is implicitly generated in a c++ program. I don't quiet understand why it requires to have a double ampersand next to the parameter data type. I understand that double ampersand means a reference to a rvalue, but I don't see how that can be applied to this context.

Comment: What kind of parameter would you expect it to have?

Comment: An r value reference can be moved from, that's where move semantics come in to play.  Do you not understand what it means to move vs. copy?

Comment: I think I do. Copy creates an exact copy of the parameter object while move doesn't create a copy but forward the address of the parameter object and destroys the current reference.

Comment: @itachi_uchiha That's not the case. A move is like a copy, but where you know that you can cannibalize the object. In practice, this makes it much cheaper; it usually amounts to copying the bytes that are on the stack. For a `std::vector`, a copy would have to copy every element on the heap-allocated array, whereas a move could simply copy the pointer to the array.

Comment: Yes.. a pointer is an address

Comment: It's a pointer to the `std::vector`'s data, not to the `std::vector` itself.  "move doesn't create a copy but forward the address of the parameter object" is absolutely incorrect.  For example, move constructing a `std::array<int, 100>` is no different from copying it because none of its data is dynamically allocated, and so it can't be reused for a different object.

Comment: what's the difference between object and data?. When you create a var ex: int a = 5, a is the name that you use to reference some object in memory.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the move constructor is to take ownership of the resources of an object that is about to be destroyed anyway, in order to save the cost of a copy. An object that is about to be destroyed anyway is an r-value. So the parameter type of the move constructor is a reference to an r-value.

What else could it be? It can't be an l-value reference, that's the copy constructor. And we can't take by value, because that would invoke the copy constructor (and also be ambiguous with it), defeating the whole purpose of the move constructor.

Comment: Yes, and to take ownership of that object, you need the address, so the new reference can take on the new memory space; however, I don't know if I am misinterpreting the definition of rvalue. An rvalue to me is just simply a value that can't be assigned to the left side of the = operator, ex: int a = b*c. b*c is an rvalue and I think that your claim makes sense in this case when you say "An object that is about to be destroyed anyway is an r-value" because it looks like b*a is immediately destroyed after the assignment statement.

Comment: You aren't taking ownership of the object: you're cannibalizing it's internals. You might be confusing the idea of rvalues with rvalue references a bit: Rvalue references are ***NOT rvalues***. Rvalue references are used to extend the lifetime of temporary objects, when returned from some operation.